# Background process

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, automation

I have the below script -

```
#!/bin/bash
xset -dpms
xset s off
openbox-session &
start-pulseaudio-x11
xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr

/usr/bin/nm-connection-editor

openfortivpn gw.itsecurelink.com:64443 --username lezor -p secretpassword --trusted-cert 944d1bda4d036757016b1aecea923572351fafb9f48a58a84b98742f5e5c105690 


while true; do
xfreerdp /v:192.168.20.122 /u:'' /f /sec:tls /cert-ignore
done
```

For some reason, the VPN part " openfortivpn " , runs and dies basically instantly. However the while true; do loop works fine and RDP launches.

I need to somehow send this openfortivpn into the background. I've tried using nohup and the & sign.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this. I switched to the other user via sudo, ran the script and found that it was a permission issue that the user didn't have full access to run the VPN. Ran chmod to give 777 on the directory/files of the VPN and it worked out fine.